# $_GET["page"] variable not working in localhost but working in production

Tags: php, routes

I am looking at a php site that was developed by somebody else some time ago.

There is a variable that assumedly should be absorbing the REQUEST_URI variable.

```
$index_pag_request = (isset($_GET["page"])) ? $_GET["page"] : 'home';
$index_pDAO = new PageDAO();
```

Now this works fine in production, but once I managed to bully a local instance into operation there is no `"page"` variable being passed.
Am something of a novice with php so feel like I'm missing something obvious but the variable (in this case `"by-laws"` seems to be appearing by magic in production but not locally...

I've scanned through every included/required file and there doesn't appear to be anything there to set it.

One potential issue is that the server is on v5.6 of php, and my laptop is running v7.3 (I know... but trying to get homebrew to play on Monterey with old versions of php was no fun...)

$_SERVER output below

```
[DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /Users/blahblah/public_html
[REMOTE_ADDR] => ::1
[REMOTE_PORT] => 49386
[SERVER_SOFTWARE] => PHP 7.3.33 Development Server
[SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
[SERVER_NAME] => localhost
[SERVER_PORT] => 9000
[REQUEST_URI] => /by-laws
[REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
[SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /Users/blahblah/public_html/index.php
[PATH_INFO] => /by-laws
[PHP_SELF] => /index.php/by-laws
[HTTP_HOST] => localhost:9000
[HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
[HTTP_SEC_CH_UA] => "Chromium";v="106", "Google Chrome";v="106", "Not;A=Brand";v="99"
[HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_MOBILE] => ?0
[HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_PLATFORM] => "macOS"
[HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
[HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
[HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE] => same-origin
[HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE] => navigate
[HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER] => ?1
[HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST] => document
[HTTP_REFERER] => http://localhost:9000/404
[HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate, br
[HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7
[HTTP_COOKIE] => PHPSESSID=a3469ff8prncevpn0nejsr1eoe
[REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1667856850.9994
[REQUEST_TIME] => 1667856850
```

That `PHP_SELF` variable looks wrong to me aswell, maybe that's a clue.

Any ideas? Feel like I am missing something really dumb?

(Edit) I should note that (having been nudged by a comment) that if I add the parameter `?page=by-laws` then it works fine, which suggests it's not being wiped, just not created.

.htaccess file below:

```
AddHandler php56-script .php
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/blahblah/

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$    index.php?page=$1    
[QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$    index.php?page=$1&page_reference=$2    [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$    index.php?page=$1&page_reference=$2&page_reference2=$3    [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Your production system is probably using URL rewriting to transform the _friendly_ URL `/by-laws` to `index.php?page=by-laws`. How this is done depends on the HTTP server (ag Apache, NGINX, IIS, etc)

Comment: _"trying to get homebrew to play on Monterey with old versions of php was no fun"_... The answer is Docker ~ `docker pull php:5.6-apache`

Comment: @Phil Any obvious easy way for someone who's much more comfortable with Ruby to check that?

Comment: Like I said, depends on the web server. If Apache, there could be a `.htaccess` file or VHost config with `RewriteRule` configurations. If NGINX, you'd look for `try_files` configurations. If IIS, well... good luck with that

Comment: Search terms to use would be _"php friendly urls <insert web server>"_. There's plenty of posts on StackOverflow and ServerFault for various servers

Comment: Normally in MVC all traffics are routed to index.php and then the URL is parsed by a function like getURL() and the function delimits the URL by '/' and first element is the page.